# WP Query and date format

Tags: wp-query, sort, date-time

I've been using a CPT named "session" that has some date fields. Those date fields are stored via the CMB2 plugin with something like this :

```
$cmb->add_field( array(
    'name' => __('Begin :', 'cmb2'),
    'id' => $prefix . 'session_datebegin',
    'desc' => __( 'Beginning date of the session', 'cmb2' ),
    'type' => 'text_date',
    'date_format' => 'd-m-Y'
) );
```

Now I want to display the sessions, ordered by the "closest" date. Here are the args used in my WP query :

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'session', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'session_datebegin', 
    'orderby' => 'session_datebegin', 
    'order' => 'ASC' 
    );
```

Let's say I have 3 dates : 22-04-2016, 20-04-2016 and 05-05-2016. The previous query gives : 05-05-2016, 20-04-2016, 22-04-2016. As you guessed, using "DESC" instead of "ASC" returned : 22-04-2016, 20-04-2016, 05-05-2016.

The date settings for my WP install are custom ones, under this form : d-m-Y.

I just can't figure out where the problem takes place : for "may", even there is a confusion somewhere with the US date format, 05-05-2016 will always be equal to 05-05-2016, won't it ?!

How can I make a proper sort with this date format ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For those who experienced the same problem, I finally found a way to do the sort. First I created an extra CMB like this :

```
$cmb->add_field( array(
        'id' => $prefix . 'session_gooddatebegin',
        'type' => 'hidden',
    ) );
```

Then I created an action using `save_post`. If the CPT "session" is being updated, thanks to `$update`, I assume that the user selected a date in the CMB `session_datebegin`. Hence, we now are able to update the hidden date field, putting it to the correct form :

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'good_dates', 99, 3);

function good_dates( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

    if (get_post_type($post_id)!='session') {
        return;
    }

    //if the post is being updated
    if ($update==true) {

        //begin date 
        $datebegin = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'session_datebegin', true );

        //put to the expected form with date() and strtotime() 
        $datebegingood = date("mdY", strtotime($datebegin));

        //update the hidden variable
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'session_gooddatedeb', $datebegingood );
    }

}
```

Finally, the sort can be performed in the archive page using the same args as before :

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'session', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'session_datebegin', 
    'orderby' => 'session_datebegin', 
    'order' => 'ASC' 
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell this is a poor format to store date.

You get results you get because 05 < 20 < 22 in that example. You are merely comparing strings and in *these* date strings day of the month is leading.

You wouldn't be able to easily cast it to MySQL DATE either since that one got YYYY-MM-DD format.

If you need sort you should store your dates in string–sortable format like DATE or store timestamps, which can be sorted as numbers (not human readable though).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Though, CMB2 developpers state that text-date is stored as UNIX TIMESTAMP, that is the reason why I thought those dates could be sorted...

Comment: Ah, I think I missed the issue in your code — `orderby` should be `meta_value` or `meta_value_num`, not name of the key.

Comment: thanks, but the problem remains the same.

Comment: Well, no telling what's wrong then. In general if timestamp is stored and arguments are correct WP should be perfectly capable of such sort.

Comment: I also tried meta_type => 'DATE' to cast the value